# Separate label from textbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to separate a label from a textbox?

I found that this is supposed to work :

1. Select the controls
2. Arrange tab
3. Remove layout

But the remove layout button is always disabled... Probably cause it's only when you use the tabular or stacked option

[image]

Is there any other way to do it, or am I doing something wrong?

Please, don't tell me that I have to copy/paste the label and delete the original one.

Thank you

Comment: Select label, ctrl+x, ctrl+v ... Remove layout is only about the way that controls are joined in a group.

Comment: Alright, I feel stupid now.. I thought there could be a proper way like a button to dissociate them. Write that as an answer and lets forget this question

Comment: The problem that way is when I copy they always go to the top corner and I have to move them back. And the reason why I wanted to separate them is I want to move the textboxes a little bit with the keys on the keyboard without the label moving with it. Cause I'm really bad aligning them with the mouse.

Comment: Ah! Do not use the mouse, do not detach the labels. Learn to use the align buttons. Gimme a minute.

Comment: The align buttons? the stacked and tabular thing?

Comment: I found it!! I don't know how many hours I raged trying to align with the top properties. That will make me save a lot of time. Thank you!!!

Comment: @remou Did you get the email for the microsoft mvp nomination btw?

Comment: No, but I doubt they are fast, thanks again :)

Comment: @Remou They put me in CC in the email and I think with their discussion you got really good chances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use remove layout if you can select that little cross.

[image: remove layout]

Use the align buttons to tidy up this mess.

[image: align]

Answer (score 12):

To move a text box (or any control) independently from its label is to click and drag the control using the large grey box in the top left of the control. This allows you complete freedom of placement between the control and label.

Answer (score 8):

Remove layout only works if you use either tabular or stacked.

Use the square at the top right to move them separately, and select only the label to delete the label.

Just select the one you want to use only, and it can be controlled separately. Also: width, height, top, and left in the properties tab are your friends.

Comment: At the end of the days, top and left are NOT my friends. I used to work with them but you need to be patient. Thank you for your answer thought.

Comment: Fair enough, they help me line things up quite a bit because you can't zoom in access for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, it's good when you want the exact same width and height

Answer (score 2):

I do not use Access much so I find letting Access create all the labels is quicker, when separating the label from the data I use the following method.

- Click the label
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy label
- Delete to remove label
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste label back to form
- Drag from top left to roughly the location you want

If you have a column of labels then do the cut/copy/paste/reposition for all of them first, then use the method **Fionnuala** shows to align all to right.
If the labels are too far to the left or right the use the cursor keys to move.

Again use **Fionnuala** method to align the rows.

If you find they do not align as expected then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to step back.

Answer (score 0):

If Remove Layout is not available, select Stacked, *which will make Remove Layout available*, and then select Remove Layout.

This also keeps things where they are, so less re-aligning afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got the right answer. Select the Label and send click "Send to back" on Arrange Tab. Label will be detached. Now move it anywhere as required.